# Store dynamic Multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

Dynamic multidimensional array is coming in following form:

```
coordinates:"[75.07760579,29.93068379]"
```

from some API call.

Now if there are 10 different coordinates, I want to store each 10 coordinates into array say `Lattitude=[]` and `Longitude=[]`

Lattitude will comprise of 75.07760579

Longitude  will 29.93068379

Can anybody help:

I am doing it in following way:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    header: header,
    url: '../../api/..../' + ouid + '.json?fields=[coordinates]',
    success: function (response) {

        var coordinates = response.coordinates;
        lattitude.push.apply(coordinates);
    },
    error: function (response) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please post multiple coordinates example here?

Comment: Say I am calling api 10 times then 10 different coordinates will come like following way:

Comment: Say I am calling api 10 times then 10 different coordinates will come like following way:   coordinates:"[65.0760579,29.93068379]"                 coordinates:"[43.07760579,35.93068379]"                                                                     coordinates:"[67.07760579,12.93068379]"..................

Comment: JSON.parse(coordinates);

latitude.push(coordinates[0])
longitude.push(coordinates[1])

Comment: And make latitude and longitude as Global arrays

Comment: longitude---7
latitude---[

Comment: JSON.parse(response.coordinates);
            latitude.push(response.coordinates[0]) ;
            longitude.push(response.coordinates[1]);
           console.log("longitude---"+longitude);
            console.log("latitude---"+latitude);                                                       It is giving following output: longitude---7
latitude---[

Comment: Check My answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// YOUR CASE YOU WILL GET IN AJAX RESPONSE "response.coordinates"
var response = {
  coordinates: "[75.07760579,29.93068379]"
};
var latitude = [] , longitude = [];
var coordinates = JSON.parse(response.coordinates);

latitude.push(coordinates[0]);
longitude.push(coordinates[0]);

console.log(latitude, longitude)
```